# Dreamspark Visual Studio 2013 RC

Tags: visual-studio, msdn, dreamspark

Will we see a release of VS2013 RC on Dreamspark (Student version of MSDN)?
I wish to download vs2013RC. But not a trial one.. On microsoft's site, it has a trial download link which ends after 90 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is out as of today (27 Oct). Note that while the ad mentions only the Professional edition being available on Dreamspark, you can also download the Premium. However as far as the Ultimate edition goes - which contains the new CodeLens feature - is still available only in RC. It is not yet clear whether VS Ultimate (final) will be available on Dreamspark.

Comment: As of today (10 Nov) the Ultimate version is also available, happy downloading :)

Answer (score 0):

Also I see that Vs2013 RTM is released on dreamspark now.